# JSDoc @param together with @deprecated

Tags: javascript, deprecated, jsdoc, param

I have a JavaScript function getting some parameters including object types. However, one property of a parameter, which is an object, will be used as deprecated. I would like to indicate this situation in the documentation, however I don't know how to use @param tag with @deprecated. Consider the example below:

```
/**
* This function does something.
*
* @name myFunction
* @function
* @since 3.0
* @param {function} [onSuccess] success callback
* @param {function} [onFailure] failure callback
* @param {object} [options] options for function
* @param {string} [options.lang] display language
* @param {string} [options.type] type of sth
*/

this.myFunction= function (onSuccess, onFailure, options) {
    //do something
}
```

I want to deprecate "type" property of "options" object. How can I do that, or can I?

Comment: I'm going to precede the parameter description with `DEPRECATED: `. Then I'll `console.log` something if a user touches it.

Comment: You can't deprecate parameters or properties, but you should mark the @param as optional like this `@param {string=}`

Comment: @Droogans of course, it is possible to inform the user about deprecated parameters in any way. I just wonder if there is a standardized way.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia "optional" may be a way to show the user that the parameter is not mandadory, but still does not seem to match the exact meaning of "deprecated". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 15):

[Official JSDoc documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-deprecated) does not indicate that the `@deprecated` tag can be used for deprecating anything else than an entire symbol.

The `@deprecated` tag can be used to document that for example a function as a whole has been deprecated.

```
/**
 * @deprecated since version 2.0.0
 */
function old () {

}
```

You can of course, as @Droogans said in the comments, add something like `deprecated:`  in front of the `@param` description. If a developer somehow still ends up using the deprecated feature, you could implement a warning of some sorts.

```
/**
 * @param  {string=} bar - Deprecated: description
 */
function foo (bar) {
  if (bar) {
    console.warn('Parameter bar has been deprecated since 2.0.0')
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be cool if something like `@deprecated(param)` existed

Answer (score 11):

A suggestion is using typescript, like so:

```
function test(
  options: {
    /**
     * @deprecated use newName instead
     */
    name?: string,
    newName?: string
  }) {
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this was downvoted because the question is about JSDoc, but this is what I was actually looking for. It will instruct the TS compiler to mark that property as deprecated.

Comment: It'll mark the property as deprecated, but the question was about marking a param.  In order to follow the question, it'd need to mark the entire options object as deprecated.

Comment: @Darc, yes, and the annotation is also applicable for options too.